# How to make object from one component 'lookAt' another object in another component?

Tags: react-three-fiber

I'm fairly new to both React and Threejs and am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to make an object from one component lookAt another object from another component using react-three-fiber and @react-three/drei. I have a custom [PerspectiveCamera with controls](https://github.com/DePasqualeOrg/three-immersive-controls) in one component and some Text using @react-three/drei in another component. What I would like to happen is have the Text and planeGeometry face the camera at all times

Any help would be great! CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-chaplygin-hihx70?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the [Billbloard](https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/abstractions-billboard--billboard-text-story) component does just that. Not sure if it works in a `VRCanvas` though

Comment: Thanks @rustyBucketBay, but unfortunately that doesn't work. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-swanson-m8nk5v?file=/src/components/Cubes.js